# I keep getting ERROR 500 when connecting to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a register and login page using HTML and PHP but I keep getting an ERROR 500.

```
<?php

    $Fname = $_POST['FName'];
    $Lname = $_POST['LName'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];

    // Connect to MySQL
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'users');

    if($conn->connect_error) {
        die('Connection Error: '. $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
        $insert = "INSERT INTO user_form(first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $conn.prepare($insert); // <--
        $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $Fname, $Lname, $Email, $Password);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo 'Registered';
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();

    }
?>
```

I'm using MAMP for my localhost and the database was created in phpmyadmin. I'm pretty sure the ERROR comes up at `$stmt = $conn.prepare($insert);` but it may be somewhere else too.

Comment: Try to use `$conn->prepare()`

Comment: Dot notation does not exist in PHP. You need to use arrow syntax `->` .